# How to read body of HttpRequest POSTed to a REST web service - IBM Integration Bus

Tags: json, web-services, rest, httprequest

I am exposing a Rest based POST API and have to read few parameters in the body along with header. I am able to fetch the query string (header) parameters using HTTP Input node query string parser. As i have configured Input parser to JSON, it can not parse the incoming message and gives a runtime exception :

> JSON parsing errors have occurred

Content-Type is set to :

> application/x-www-form-urlencoded

I am very newbie with Rest/ JSON services on IIB. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but why didn't you set the Content-Type to application/json?

Comment: @VincentS I think your question is valid. I did try with that as well. but it still says JSON parsing errors occured.

Comment: I would definitely let the Content-Type on application/json, but apparently, you are sending an invalid JSON. Could you edit your question to add your JSON object you are sending?

Comment: @VincentS I was playing around with the request in Postman right now. What i did was, change the body message type to 'raw' and paste a valid JSON message in the body editor. I set the content-type to 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'. Now the JSON parser is able to parse the contents. So i believe this is down to the caller on how he/she set the paramters, but i cannot restrict them to do what i did. Correct?

Comment: Exact, the caller has to set the parameters correctly to allow you to read the content.